# Q: Flutter plugin just_audio

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-plugin

On Both iOS & Android when trying to change audio file source to assets I get error:
`unable to load asset`

I took code from example located at [here(pub.dev)](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) and replaced

```
    _player.setUrl("https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-episodes/scifri20181123-episode.mp3").catchError((error) {
      // catch audio error ex: 404 url, wrong url ...
      print(error);
    });
```

to this:
`_player.setAsset("06 My Baby Left Me.mp3");`
also created folder in project called `assets` with above file and updated `pubspec.yaml` accordingly.

Full error log:

```
W/o.justaudiodem(18220): Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioTrack;->getLatency()I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/ExoPlayerImpl(18220): Init b3b9aa8 [ExoPlayerLib/2.11.4] [a40, SM-A405FN, samsung, 29]
E/flutter (18220): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: 06 My Baby Left Me.mp3
E/flutter (18220): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
E/flutter (18220): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18220): #1      AudioPlayer.setAsset (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:279:41)
E/flutter (18220): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18220): #2      _MyAppState.initState (package:justaudiodemo/main.dart:28:13)
E/flutter (18220): #3      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4640:58)
E/flutter (18220): #4      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4476:5)
E/flutter (18220): #5      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter (18220): #6      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter (18220): #7      RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1148:16)
E/flutter (18220): #8      RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1119:5)
E/flutter (18220): #9      RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1061:17)
E/flutter (18220): #10     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2607:19)
E/flutter (18220): #11     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1060:13)
E/flutter (18220): #12     WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:941:7)
E/flutter (18220): #13     WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:922:7)
E/flutter (18220): #14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1180:38)
E/flutter (18220): #15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter (18220): #16     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
E/flutter (18220): #17     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1019:23)
E/flutter (18220): #18     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
E/flutter (18220): #19     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter (18220): #20     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1003:23)
E/flutter (18220): #21     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:23:15)
E/flutter (18220): #22     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:398:19)
E/flutter (18220): #23     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:429:5)
E/flutter (18220): #24     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
E/flutter (18220):
```

any help very much appreciated.

Comment: can you remove all the spaces from your asset and see if that works? - also, please post the file structure of your assets folder

Answer (score 0):

How do you update your `pubspec.yml`? I'm assuming, you did something like this:

```
assets:
  - assets/
```

If so, you might need to add `assets` in front of your filename.
Instead of doing this:

```
_player.setAsset("06 My Baby Left Me.mp3");
```

You should:

```
_player.setAsset("assets/06 My Baby Left Me.mp3");
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of just_audio are you using?
You try to use 0.3.3 to load assets audio file.

```
just_audio: ^0.3.3
```